# How to write csv file in apache spark using SparkR?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, sparkr, file-writing

I am able to load data Successfully using following commands

```
sc = sparkR.init(master = 'local', sparkPackages = 'com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0')
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
ss <- read.df(sqlContext, '/home/anmol/Downloads/Rgraphics/dataSets/states.csv', source = "com.databricks.spark.csv", inferSchema = "true")
head(ss)
```

I have tried the following command

```
write.df(df, '/home/anmol/faithfull.csv', source = 'com.databricks.spark.csv', 'overwrite')
```

but it gives following error

> 16/06/10 18:28:26 ERROR RBackendHandler: save on 261 failed Error in
>   invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
>         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.databricks.spark.csv.util.CompressionCodecs$
>         at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:189)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:222)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.save(DataFrame.scala:2027)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:141)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:86)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:38)
>         at io.netty.channel.

Comment: What makes you think you use Scala 2.11?

Comment: definitely a version error like zero323 pointed out. use spark-csv_2.10 instead

Comment: i am not using  Scala 2.11 zero323

Comment: but you are using com.databricks:spark-csv_**2.11**:1.4.0 that's compiled for scala 2.11

Comment: than how am i able to read data from csv

Comment: I have instaled scala 2.11.7 still it dosen't work same problem able to read not able to write

Comment: It is not about which version is installed. It is about version which has been used to compile Spark that has to match version of the packages you download. With provided binaries use 2.10

Comment: thank you it worked zero323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the version that is being used to compile my apache spark
it was 2.10
so i used

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master = 'local', sparkPackages = 'com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0')
```

you can check yours by logging into spark-shell it gives the version of scala while starting up